# Eclipse deployment error could not autogenerate web.xml

Tags: java, eclipse, web.xml, vaadin7, servlet-3.0

So I have developped a vaadin app following [this tutorial](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/tutorial.html) but when I want to deploy it to google app engine, Eclipse fails with an internal error:

```
Could not auto-generate file (pathtoworkspace)/myproject/target/WEB-INF/web.xml
```

As far as I understand, under servlet 3.0, I only need this snippet to generate web.xml automatically

```
@WebServlet(urlPatterns = "/*", name = "MyUIServlet", asyncSupported = true)
@VaadinServletConfiguration(ui = MyUI.class, productionMode = true)
```

Is there something else i'm missing?

EDIT:

OK I just realized the WEB-INF folder was not in the path above but in

```
(pathtoworkspace)/projectname/src/main/webapp/*
```

How do I change where Eclipse looks?

In the properties menu->Google->Web application, the WAR directory is set to

```
 src/main/webapp
```

so no problem on this side.